# django-oauth2-provider: get the token without sending the client_secret

Tags: python, django, oauth-2.0

I'm using django-oauth2-provider with rest-framework to provide authentication in my API. 
My mobile app is going to connect to my REST API to retrieve some data. No third party apps are going to get involved in the process.

According to [this](http://aaronparecki.com/articles/2012/07/29/1/oauth2-simplified#others), the grant type required for this use case would be the password grant. Since it's a bad idea to store the secret in the device, I need to access the token without it.

I tried to send a request without the secret:

```
curl -X POST -d "client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&grant_type=password&username=user&password=pass" http://localhost:8000/oauth2/access_token/
```

But the response I get is:

```
{"error": "invalid_client"}
```

My question is whether it is possible to do this with django-oauth2-provider, and how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

1. Set `Authorization Grant Type` as `Resource owner password-based`
2. Put `WSGIPassAuthorization On` at same place as `WSGIScriptAlias`

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a client through django admin UI and replace "MY_CLIENT_ID" with the ID.

Comment: I already did that. The problem is that without sending the client secret too, there is no way I can get the token data. I always get the invalid_client error. So what I need is a way to get the token without sending the client secret.

Answer (score 1):

"Client type" of application should be "public"

Answer (score 1):

Just to combine solutions. This is what worked for me. Follow through on the [Getting Started guide](https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rest-framework/getting_started.html). However, on creating the application, provide the following:

- Name: A name of your choosing
- Client Type: Public
- Authorization Grant Type: Resource owner password-based

Then the request should be:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "grant_type=password&username=<username>&password=<password>&client_id=<client_id>" http://localhost:8000/o/token/
```

or, if JSON,
to settings.py add:

```
OAUTH2_PROVIDER = {
    # expect request body Content Type application/json
    'OAUTH2_BACKEND_CLASS': 'oauth2_provider.oauth2_backends.JSONOAuthLibCore'
}
```

```
curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:8000/o/token/ \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
    "grant_type": "password",
    "client_id": "<client_id>",
    "username": "<username>",
    "password": "<password>"
}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use password grant type. The following curl command works with django-oauth-toolkit. I believe it should work with any other oauth provider as well.

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d 'grant_type=password&username=user&password=pass&client_id=client_id' 'http://localhost:8000/o/token/'
```

Please see the following link for more info: https://aaronparecki.com/articles/2012/07/29/1/oauth2-simplified#password